# Openlog + Lilypad Simple board - not writing to SD card

Tags: sd-card

I'm desperately trying to get my openlog to work and write data out to a micro SD card with no luck.

I'm using a battery-powered lilypad arduino simple board and have attached L-shaped female headers to to the openlog to plug it right in. I am also using an FTDI breakout with the lilypad to download code and that is working. I think i have matched the RX and TX properly by flipping the openlog over as it pictured in the images attached. I'm using the example code included on the sparkfun openlog page just to test:

https://github.com/sparkfun/OpenLog/blob/master/firmware/examples/OpenLog_Test_Sketch/OpenLog_Test_Sketch.ino

There are no lights lit on the openlog which might indicate a power issue - but it's super unclear.

Any ideas or help very welcome!

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Are you sure all the pins match up, except for TX/RX?

Comment: In your picture you are using a 32  gig card. In addition to being expensive overkill, that is probably SDXC and may not be something the logger supports.

Comment: It's not overkill, it's a card I already had using it in camera. That's not the issue - it's not getting power.